# Powershell script to rename OneDrive for Business URL?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, onedrive-for-business, onedrive

Is there a way to rename the OneDrive Sync SharePoint URL ? without manual interruption

I have OneDrive synced to http://siteA/test/form/allitem.aspx. Now I want to rename it to http://siteB/test/form/allitem.aspx. So that it can point out to the new site and sync automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it’s not feasible to change the sync location of OneDrive for Business to SharePoint using PowerShell Script.

We need to change the location manually.

Reference: [Change the location where you sync SharePoint libraries on your computer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-location-where-you-sync-SharePoint-libraries-on-your-computer-ca8a88f6-bc4f-4ec2-a460-864c4e9b2be0)